# Implementation of finding an index in a 1D array for a triangular grid

Tags: algorithm, grid

Am using a while loop to find an index within a 1D array, is there an easier, less-time-consuming and/or mathmatical way to find the index?

Consider the next grid:

```
 4   o
     |\  
     | \ 
     |  \
 3   o---o
     |\  |\  
     | \ | \ 
     |  \|  \
 2   o---o---o
     |\  |\  |\  
     | \ | \ | \ 
     |  \|  \|  \
 1   o---o---o---o
     |\  |\  |\  |\  
     | \ | \ | \ | \ 
     |  \|  \|  \|  \
 0   o---o---o---o---o

     0   1   2   3   4
```

To find an index in the triangular grid within a 1D array I have the next function:

```
//int size = 5;
int getindex( int x, int y )
{

    int columnCount = size;
    while( y-- > 0 ) x += columnCount--;

    return x;

}
```

The array (The numbers within the parenthesis are the coordinates and to simplify your view, in reality the (x,y) is in its whole the data):

```
pointdata data[ 15 ] = {
    (0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0),
    (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (3,1),
    (0,2), (1,2), (2,2),
    (0,3), (1,3),
    (0,4),
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather problem to sum numbers between *n* and *m*, which is pretty widely known: it is sum of numbers 1 to *m* minus sum of numbers 1 to *n*(n-1 infact, but it gets eliminated in the code) plus *x*, ofcourse. In your example, it is:

`index = columnCount * ( columnCount + 1 ) / 2 - ( columnCount - y ) * ( columnCount - y + 1 ) / 2 ) + x;`

plus, since column count is static (presumably), you can pre-cumpute the first part or even better just use total length of your array.

Comment: Column count is indeed static but what do you mean by pre-compute the first part. The first row?

Comment: The point is the idea what you need - compute total count of members on previous rows. Code is irrelevant. You can also compute average of largest row and y-1 row and multiply it be y.

Comment: @brainoverflow sum from 1 to *m* is static. Sum from 1 to *n* is based on y.